# How do we decide the direction of vector, that is orthogonal to some other vector?

Tags: vectors

assume that two vector given with relationship below: $$\vec{n}\cdot \vec{u} = 0 $$ Then $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{u}$ are orthogonal vectors. Assume that we now have the direction of $\vec{n}$

Then there are infinitely many possible direction for $\vec{u}$
[image: Coordinate System]

How do we choose the vector $\vec{u}$?

When we consider vector valued functions, we choose Normal vector to be directed inner side of the curve.

When we consider grad $\nabla$ we know that it is perpendicular to any level curve. Then we choose $\nabla$ to be directed towards outward of the curve.

How do we decide direction? What is the algorithm behind that? What am I missing? Or is it application dependent?

Comment: Actually there are infinitely many possible direction, and also magnitude for $\vec{u}$. The set of all these $\vec{u}$ can be called as the orthogonal complement of $\vec{n}$. The dimension of this set is n-1 (assuming $\vec{n}$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ vector).

Comment: A.P warned me about that issue. I have corrected it, thanks for your interest

Comment: Welcome XD. Concerning the grad, I think it points to the direction such that the scalar valued function increased fastest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much application dependent. Note that in $\Bbb{R}^3$ there are *infinitely many* vectors orthogonal to a given vector, not just $4$. Indeed, if $\vec{n} = (a,b,c)$ and $\vec{u} = (x,y,z)$, then
$$
0 = \vec{n}\cdot\vec{u} = ax + by + cz
$$
is the equation of a plane through the origin.

---

In the case of the normal vector $\vec{n}$ to a curve $\gamma$ at some point $p$, you can describe the choice in the following (impractical) way:

1. Consider the tangent vector $\vec{t}$ at $\gamma$ in $p$.
2. The unit vectors orthogonal to $\vec{t}$ parametrise all the planes containing $\vec{t}$. Consider the [osculating plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_plane) $\pi$ of $\gamma$ at $p$ (which is uniquely determined).
3. Unless $\vec{n} = 0$ (in which case $\gamma$ has a flex point at $p$), the line through $p$ with direction $\vec{t}$ divides $\pi$ in two half-planes. The projection of $\gamma$ on $\pi$ is contained in one of them, which we call $H$.
4. The vector $\vec{n}/\|\vec{n}\|$ is uniquely determined as the unit vector orthogonal to $\vec{t}$ which is contained in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, your right. There are infinitely many vectors.

Comment: As an example I added a "synthetic" description of the choice of direction for the normal vector to a curve at a point. Does it help?

Comment: I didnt understand osculating plane part. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It is the plane which has the largest order of contact with $\gamma$ at $p$. Intuitively, you can think of it as the plane through $p$ that is closest to $\gamma$. It's a bit like with tangent lines: even though there are infinitely many lines that intersect $\gamma$ exactly at $p$, there is only one which has order of contact (i.e. intersection multiplicity) $\geq 2$ with $\gamma$ at $p$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special case for twice-differentiable curves acting in $R^3$ For any point of such a curve you can explicitly define an orthonormal basis in $R^3$ that includes the normalized direction and two orthonormal vectors.

The trick is to realize that if $f''$ exists and is and not zero

$(f'(t) \cdot f'(t))' = 0 =  2f''(t)\cdot f'(t) = 0$

and it follows that

$(\frac{f'(t)}{||f'(t)||}, \frac{f''(t)}{||f''(t)||}, \frac{f'(t)}{||f'(t)||} \times \frac{f''(t)}{||f''(t)||})$

is an orthonormal basis in $R^3$.